# pizzalist is not defined in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, ejs, web-development-server

I'm making a blog and I want the blogs to appear on the home/default page. I know the variables are pizzas, but that's because it's my teachers code and her code was about ordering pizza. I have index.js and index.ejs, the server is up and I have a schema and all the necessary information needed.

Here's the error message:
C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\CIT\PostU\pizza_example\views\index.ejs:20 18| 19|  >> 20| <% for(var i=0; i < pizzalist.length; i++) { %> 21|  22| 23| <%= pizzalist[i].name %> pizzalist is not defined

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const pizzas = require('../models/pizza');

const router = express.Router();
/* GET home page. */

router.route('/')
.get((req,res,next) => {
    res.render('index.ejs', { title: 'Pizza shop' });   
})

.post((req, res, next) => {
  pizzas.create(req.body)
  .then((pizzacreated) => {
      pizzas.find()
       .then((pizzasfound) => {
              res.render('index',{'pizzalist' : pizzasfound, title:'All Pizzas'} );
      }, (err) => next(err))
  .catch((err) => next(err));
  }, (err) => next(err))
  .catch((err) => next(err));
})

.put((req, res, next) => {
  res.statusCode = 403;
  res.end('PUT operation not supported on /pizzas/create');
})

.delete((req, res, next) => {
  res.statusCode = 403;
  res.end('Delete operation not  supported on /pizzas/creste');
  
});
module.exports = router;
```

and here's the index.ejs code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
        <% include partials/head %>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1><%= title %></h1>
            <div class="ra-r"></div>
            <body>
            <table class="table table-inverse">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Customer</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% for(var i=0; i < pizzalist.length; i++) { %>
     <tr>

       <td><%= pizzalist[i].name %></td>
       <td><%= pizzalist[i].description %></td>
       <td><%= pizzalist[i].customer %></td>


     </tr>
  <% } %>
    </tbody>

  </table>

</body>
</div>
</div>
<% include partials/foot %>

</html>
```

Comment: Please update your question to include an actual question, this is just a dump of code. If you're getting an error message, what's the actual message? Can you cut down the code sample even more to demonstrate the problem. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - it's hard to figure out what you want here other than general "help".

Comment: updated my question

Comment: You forgot the actual code `index.ejs` in which the error occurs